# How to understand and parse this long sentences with so many attributive clauses?

Tags: sentence-construction

From an interview in 2/21/2014 published by [*Time*](http://nation.time.com/2014/02/21/tim-draper-six-californias-proposal-qa/): “The Man Who Wants To Split California Into 6 States”

> You /said /in another interview /that [if /the government /of
> California /served /residents /the way [that /Google /serves/
> employees ][that /it /buses /down from San Francisco /to Silicon
> Valley, ***that /you / wouldn’t have proposed /this.*** Can you /expand on/that?

There are so many "that" here, it is not easy for me to analyze these clauses, especially the sentence, I think the correct one should leave out "that".

So how to understand and parse this long sentence with so many attributive clauses?

Answer (score 3):

> You said in another interview that if the government of California
>   served residents the way that Google serves employees that it buses
>   down from San Francisco to Silicon Valley, that you wouldn’t have
>   proposed this. Can you expand on that?

```
You said in another interview THAT
    if the government served residents in the way THAT
        Google serves employees THAT
            it (Google) buses down,
(THAT) you wouldn't have proposed this.
```

I agree. Too many thats. I had to reread a few times. First of all, the (THAT) in the last line is extra, and really shouldn't be there. It looks like (s)he said it in the first line and accidentally repeated it. He/she could have alternately left it out in the first and added it in at the last line. Second, we could shorten this, and it would read better on paper.

```
        Google lavishly serves employees through transportation
```

It would read like this after those editions:

> You said in another interview that if the government of California
>   served residents the way that Google lavishly serves employees through transportation, you wouldn’t have
>   proposed this. Can you expand on that?

Hope that helps.

Comment: It seems the version "lavishly serves employees through transportation" expresses a particularly biased viewpoint, which does not reflect the original text. It also sounds vague compared to the shorter and more specific "…the way [Google buses their employees](https://localwiki.org/sf/Google_Bus#:~:text=Google%20runs%20a%20private%20shuttle,and%20Mountain%20View%20every%20day.), you…". [my version]

Comment: Repeating "that" is superfluous, but it serves to mark the sentence structure in a non-standard way. However the speaker could have used "**then** you wouldn’t have proposed" or similar.

Answer (score -1):

*I think this is what your sentence means:*
**You said in another interview that if the government of California served residents the way Google serves employees by busing them down from San Francisco to Silicon Valley, then you wouldn’t have proposed this. Can you expand on it?**